# Django admin text editor that is *not* WYSIWYG

Tags: django, text, django-admin, editor

Been looking at django flatpages -- and need a clean normal no-WYSIWYG editor to edit text in django admin interface. Think TextMate/Emacs/Sublime and not TinyMCE...

Is there such a thing that will help me write clean readable html code without ever going for messy WYSISYG code/text. Just a clean small simple tool. / Jens

Answer (score 0):

You can use [markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) to build static pages instead of using a WYSIWYG editor like TinyMCE. Check out http://pythonhosted.org/django-markdown/